# UITableView shows Dummy data when populated with JSON data

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I am trying to show JSON data in UITableView using custom cell, the JSON data successfully loads in table view. But, when ever I run my app for the first time, the first two rows in table view are dummy cells form IB as shown below:

[image]

My custom cell is shown below:

[image]

And the main thing is when ever I swipe up my table view the two dummy cells named (Workout) disappears, and the table view becomes like this,

[image]

How do I solve this problem?

My code is shown below:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataEvent.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableViewCalender.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EventCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! ScheduleTableViewCell





    let totalData = dataEvent[indexPath.row].event_start_date?.components(separatedBy: " ")
    let finalStartDate = totalData![0]

    let start2018 = finalStartDate.components(separatedBy: "-")
    let finalll2018 = start2018[0]
    let finall03 = start2018[1]
    let finallyIs = "\(finalll2018)-\(finall03)"


    if finallyIs == finalCompare{
        let finalDate = totalData![1]

        cell.startTimeLabel.text = finalDate
        cell.titleLabel.text = dataEvent[indexPath.row].event_title
        let endData = dataEvent[indexPath.row].event_end_date?.components(separatedBy: " ")
        let finalEndDate = endData![1]

        cell.endTimeLabel.text = finalEndDate

    }




    return cell
}
```

Comment: Show.Your.Code.

Comment: okey let me edit my question

Comment: okey, can you check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells are reused.

If `finallyIs != finalCompare` the labels are not populated and if there is a value from a previous use this value is displayed. You need to add an `else` clause to  assign a default value to each label.